# how to return multiple rows using a function in php

Tags: php, mysql

Look at the following code :

```
<?php

function getmangainfo($teamname)
{
    $rValue = "";
    $lValue = "";
    $query = ("SELECT pic, mn_title FROM table Where mn_team LIKE '%" . $teamname . "%' Limit 0,4 ");
    $row_data = mysql_query($query);
    while ($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($row_data)) {
        $rValue = $row['pic'];
        $lValue = $row['mn_title'];
        return "<a class='linksrepeated' href='" . $ABSPATH . "/" . $lValue . "/'> <img src='" . $rValue . "'/></a>";
    }
}
```

this function is not returning anything! I am thinking it is because that the return statement is inside the while loop. I tried many things hoping it will return the 4 results but nothing happened. the SQL query works 100%. the problem is with my function. please let me know what is wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: do - var_dump($row_data) - check what it is displaying

Comment: Why aren't you echoing the data out? Return will not work with multiple iterations (I don't believe)

Comment: the loop will always be executed once because of the `return` statement inside it.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14110189/1723893). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the `$row_data` to `$row` in your `while` statement

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($row_data))
```

because as I see the codes inside the `while`

```
$rValue = $row['pic'];
$lValue = $row['mn_title'];
```

you get your data as `$row` but your in `while` statement is `$row_data`

the problem is not on the `while` loop as the execution reaches the `return` statement, the execution pointer will exit the function(of course in the `while` statement)

but for me to make your code cleaner as i see you expect only one row in return pull out the `return` statement on your while

```
$rValue = "";
 $lValue = "";
 while ($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($row_data)) {
        $rValue = $row['pic'];
        $lValue = $row['mn_title'];
        break; //just to make sure for one row return
 }
 return "<a class='linksrepeated' href='" . $ABSPATH . "/" . $lValue . "/'> <img src='" . $rValue . "'/></a>";
```

but as the others says that you expect 4 row returns you can create a variable that would store all the returns in a single string

```
   $rValue = "";
     $lValue = "";
     $links = "";
     while ($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($row_data)) {
            $rValue = $row['pic'];
            $lValue = $row['mn_title'];
            $links .="<a class='linksrepeated' href='" . $ABSPATH . "/" . $lValue . "/'> <img src='" . $rValue . "'/></a>";
     }
     return $links
```

**reference**:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Comment: best answer of them all. you are the chosen one :P

Comment: you're the chosen one also! enjoy coding =)

Comment: @Mahan I think that "break" doesn't have to be there according to her question. In question it was said "I tried many things hoping it will return the 4 results but nothing happened. " So that appears like 4 results are expected and not 1

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getmangainfo($teamname){
    $rValue = "";
    $lValue = "";
    $query = ("SELECT pic, mn_title FROM table Where mn_team LIKE '%".$teamname."%' Limit 0,4 ");
    $row_data = mysql_query($query);
    $output=array();
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($row_data))
    {
    $rValue = $row['pic'];
    $lValue = $row['mn_title'];
    $output[]="<a class='linksrepeated' href='".$ABSPATH."/".$lValue."/'> <img src='".$rValue."'/></a>";
    }   
return $output;
}
```

Edit: Updated variable name

Comment: I get "Array" as a result no data at all!

Comment: @shnisaka yes, that array contains your data. run  print_r() on it rather than echo

Answer (score 1):

Its not giving full result set because you are 'returning' from within the loop. try the following it should help.

```
function getmangainfo($teamname){
    $rValue = "";
    $lValue = "";
    $query = ("SELECT pic, mn_title FROM table Where mn_team LIKE '%".$teamname."%' Limit 0,4 ");
    $row_data = mysql_query($query);
    $return = '';
    while($row_data = mysql_fetch_array($row_data))
    {
        $rValue = $row['pic'];
        $lValue = $row['mn_title'];
        $return .= "<a class='linksrepeated' href='".$ABSPATH."/".$lValue."/'> <img src='".$rValue."'/></a>";
    }
    return $return;
}
```